# Error in Asp .net: Uncaught ReferenceError: HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I write this java script code for copy "txid" to the clipboard but i have this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError:  HTMLButtonElement
this is my function:

```
function txidButtonCopy(txid) {
            
            var copyText = document.getElementById("txid");

            
            copyText.select();
            copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

            
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

            
            alert("txid");
        }
```

another part of code:

```
function txidButton(txid) {
            var disabled = 'disabled';

            if (txid!='') {
                disabled = '';
            }
            return '<button onclick="txidButtonCopy(' + txid + ')" ' + disabled + ' title="لینک تراکنش" class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 5px;"><i class="ion ion-ios-copy-outline"></i></button>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are grabbing the html button element by id when the element has no id. Give the element an id, or use document.getElementsByClassName.

```
function txidButton(txid) {
        var disabled = 'disabled';

        if (txid!='') {
            disabled = '';
        }
        return '<button id="txid" onclick="txidButtonCopy(' + txid + ')" ' + disabled + ' title="لینک تراکنش" class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 5px;"><i class="ion ion-ios-copy-outline"></i></button>';
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response but can you provide on my code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited my comment. Notice the button now has an id